# laravel pluck function doesn't give the result i want

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

My mongodb collection;

```
    [
         {
             "_id" : ObjectId('623204a7278eb2d65165a604'),
             "name" : "One",
             "data" : {
                        "by" : ObjectId('623204d1e0b39813dec5f9ca')
             },
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId('623205156949c5e3ab47a94e'),
            "name" : "Two",
            "data" : {
                        "by" : ObjectId('6232051cc76f3fcc90351784')
            }
        }
   ]
```

I using jenssegers/laravel-mongodb package. This is how I get data:

```
$array = MyCollection::where(...)
            ->get(['_id', 'data.by']);
```

I am doing the following operation on array:

```
$array->pluck('data.by');
```

This gives the output:

```
  [{"$oid": "623204d1e0b39813dec5f9ca"},{"$oid": "6232051cc76f3fcc90351784"}]
```

I want to data.by ids array: `['623204d1e0b39813dec5f9ca' , '6232051cc76f3fcc90351784'];`

Comment: Does doing `pluck('data.by.$oid')` work? What is the output of `dump($array->pluck('data.by'))`?

Comment: Output: [null, null]

Comment: Can you edit your question with the output of `$array->dump();` (right after you get the results)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure, but I think you can get your desired output with `map()`

These 3 lines should do the same thing.

```php
$array->pluck('data.by')->map(function ($item) { return $item->{'$oid'}; });
$array->pluck('data.by')->map(fn ($item) => $item->{'$oid'});
$array->pluck('data.by')->map->{'$oid'};
```

Comment: Gave this error: Undefined property: $oid

But this gave the result I wanted;
$array->map(fn ($item) => (string) $item->data['by']);